# Update a collection in Firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to update the field `code` in all the documents of a collection. Since it takes multiple write operations, I want to update the collection altogether.

This is the code (used batched writes as given in the documentation) :

```
const batch = writeBatch(db);
const userRef = doc(db, "users", userId)
const repoRef = doc(userRef, "repos", repo)
const filesRef= collection(repoRef, "files")

batch.update(filesRef, data);
```

The data object:

```
{
    README: {languageId: 45, code: 'slkjf', name: 'README'}
    main: {languageId: 62, name: 'main', code: 'haah'}
}
```

Error:

```
No error shown
```

What is the solution and is this the best method, or should I use a map method and recursively update the field in every document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of a call to [`WriteBatch#update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.writebatch#writebatchupdate) is a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference.md#documentreference_class). In your code you instead try to pass in a [`CollectionReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.collectionreference.md#collectionreference_class).

To write the code property of each entry in a given object to your database, you first must iterate through the object and add update operations into your batch before committing it to the server.

For the given object and references:

```
const data = {
    README: { languageId: 45, code: 'slkjf', name: 'README' },
    main: { languageId: 62, code: 'haah', name: 'main' }
}

const userDocRef = doc(db, "users", userId);
const repoDocRef = doc(userDocRef, "repos", repo);
const repoFilesColRef = collection(repoDocRef, "files");

const batch = writeBatch(db);
```

You can add update operations into the batch like so:

```
for (let [docId, fileData] of Object.entries(data)) {
  batch.update(
    doc(repoFilesColRef, docId),
    { code: fileData.code }
  );
};
```

Once you are ready to apply the changes to the server, call the commit method and handle the returned Promise object.

```
batch.commit()
  .then(() => console.log("updates successful"))
  .catch((err) => console.error("updates failed", err));
```

---

[Batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) have a limit of 500 operations per batch, so to handle that you can use this function to automatically create more batches as needed.

Note: Atomic updates are not guaranteed across multiple batches, only for each individual batch.

```
function multiWriteBatch(db) {
  let batch = writeBatch(db), batches = [batch], size = 0;

  const getBatch = () => {
    if (++size >= 500) {
      // start new batch
      batch = writeBatch(db);
      size = 0;
      batches.push(batch);
    }
    return batch;
  }

  return {
    commit: () => Promise.all(batches.map(b => b.commit())),
    delete: (ref) => getBatch().delete(ref),
    set: (...args) => getBatch().set(...args),
    update: (...args) => getBatch().update(...args)
  }
}

// usage:
const batch = multiWriteBatch(db);
// fill as normal
batch.commit()
  .then(() => console.log("all batches successful"))
  .catch((err) => console.error("one or more batches failed", err));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update all documents inside a collection so first you'll need to get all documents of this collection:

```
import { collection, query, where, getDocs, writeBatch,   } from "firebase/firestore";

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(
  query(collection(db, `users/${userId}/repos`))
)
```

Then you'll need to loop through all these documents and add the change to batch:

```
const batch = writeBatch(db)
// the error was 'doc' declared two times
// querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
// renamed to 'item'
querySnapshot.forEach((item) => {
  const docRef = doc(db, `users/${userId}/repos/${item.id}`)
  batch.update(docRef, {
    field: "Changed value"
  })
})

// write your changes
await batch.commit()
```

You can find more about this [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions?hl=pt-br).

EDIT:

If you need to handle it in `Promise.all` here's an example:

```
// add 'updateDoc' to imports

await Promise.all(querySnapshot.map(item => {
  const docRef = doc(db, `users/${userId}/repos/${item.id}`)
  await updateDoc(docRef, {
    field: "Changed value"
  })
}))
```

Just pay attention that if you use `Promise.all` and one operation fails all the rest will fail too and you’ll not know wich documents has been updated and wich has not.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Note that a batch has a limit of 500 operations. If you know there is a possibility to go over this limit, you should either cut the total operations in two or more chunks of 500 or use `Promise.all()`.

Comment: Is this the best approach though? Because I have the json object (data) to replace, with the keys as the document ids and values as field names and field values. If I implement it as you mentioned, where should I write the condition, like `data[key] == doc.id` for updating the respective code field?            Can I simply delete all the documents in the collection and add the data json? Will it consider the keys as document id and add the respective fields? Think it takes fewer operations this way.

Comment: Also following your code snippet, I got an error `TypeError: doc is not a function` at `const docRef = doc(db, users/${userId}/repos/${doc.id})`

Comment: @useDeep sorry, I've declared doc two times XD I've edited the answer and pointed what was the error

Comment: Also, about your first comment: No, firestore will not understand your JSON keys as new documents. It will understand it as a `map` key. If you need to separate everything in collections/documents so you should use `batch` and as Renaud said, if this batch is above 500 operations so you need to split it in chunks of code or use `Promise.all()`. I'll let an example of this seccond in answer too.